# Desabilitar Validators.Required Angular2

Tags: formulário, angular

Tenho o seguinte formulário utilizando Validators.

```
 this.formulario = new FormGroup({
    CodigoTemp: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
});
```

Preciso desativar o Validators.Required caso um checkbox seja marcado. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Utilizo Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `setValidators`, assim:

```
// Para utilizar uma validação
this.formulario.controls.CodigoTemp.setValidators([
    Validators.required,
]);

// Para remover as validações
this.formulario.controls.CodigoTemp.setValidators(null);
```

Vale lembrar que este método irá substituir todas as validações existentes, no caso de remover as validações, não há problema. Caso você queira adicionar uma nova validação, por exemplo, `maxLength`, deverá redefinir as validações já existentes e a nova validação que deseja, assim:

```
this.formulario.controls.CodigoTemp.setValidators([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(50),
]);
```

> Até onde eu consegui encontrar, ainda não existe uma funcionalidade para adicionar validações, como [discutido aqui](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10567).

Comment: Obrigado @celsomtrindade, é exatamente o que eu preciso e funcionou!! Porém, eu preciso utilizar isso ativando e desativando varias vezes, tipo assim:

`if(this.todosBairros == true){
     this.formulario.controls.CodigoTemp.setValidators(null);
     }else{
      this.formulario.controls.CodigoTemp.setValidators([
        Validators.required,
      ])
     }`

Porém, desta forma ele não funciona, sabe o porquê?

Comment: Pode ser algo no restante do código. Pode ser que `todosBairros` possua um valor diferente do esperado, ou que essa chamada não seja executada. Utiliza console.log para ir verificando os valores.

Comment: Eu acabei descobrindo que na html tinha um style perdido e quando eu tirei ele, tudo funcionou!!